# appdynamics: how can I exclude an exception from being counted in the "Errors per minute" metric in health rules?

Tags: appdynamics

I tried to achieve that by configuring the exception as ignored in *Configuration -> Instrumentation -> Error Detection*, under the section "Define exceptions or log messages to ignore when detecting error Transactions", but that did not work. Why? According to the documentation,

> AppDynamics still detects the exception, logs the exception,
> increments the exception count

, BUT

> AppDynamics does not count the business transaction in which the
> exception occurred as an error transaction

. So what am I missing? Doesn't the "Errors" word in "Errors per minute" metric mean the above "error transactions"? From what I see happening, it behaves as "Errors" word in "Errors per minute" are really exceptions and not "error transactions". So my question is: how can I exclude an exception from being counted in the "Errors per minute" metric in health rules (*Alert & Respond -> Health Rules*)?